# How can I animate a CNC cable track?

Tags: animation

I tried to use the *Curve* modifier ...

[image]

... but the motion isn't the same as real one.

[image]

Comment: Hello ! It might be interesting to show us what it should look like for reference

Comment: Hi..i already added the real one

Comment: switch the curve direction, maybe. and/or move the curve instead of the object

Comment: nah, not working. one end should be fixed while the other moves. it should move like this : https://i.ibb.co/qJH2j2Q/1a.jpg

Comment: believe me it works https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtS2T.gif

Comment: wow dude! how you do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the curve modifier as you probably did and move the curve.

If it does not work as expected, invert the curve direction (in edit mode for the curve, use the menu "segments/switch direction").

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much bro!!!! here as you said https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-7-91c20a329e29.gif

Answer (score 3):

This may be easy solution for you, use curve as you did with your chain and use hook on the curve... set it to object that will be your CNC head and that 1 point of the curve next to the head will be hooked to it... Result is this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

By moving the cube you can easily control whole movement, it has some limitations of course, but you can solve them as well

Here is the file for you:
[image]

Check it if you understand and see if it works, if you need to limit other movement, you should use another objects to control that curve

Comment: Hi MikoCG! nice one.. i will take a look at it right now. thanks for the blend file

Comment: @MikoCG ... by moving Cube object you don't get desired movement ... it moves also the end of cable.